# Why when I change the title of a button programatically in swift does it change the font of the button

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the font of my button set in the code storyboard; condensed Bold.

[image]

When I update the title with `self.myButton.setTitle("£\(someValue)", for: [])` it removes the original text formatting. Is there a reason for this and how do I avoid it?

Comment: You must not set the title if the title has a font. You must set the _attributed_ title.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why's it different from setting a label text though?

Comment: I don't understand the sense of the word "why" in that question. I am here to tell you how the framework works, not to justify it like some kind of theologian. By setting the style to Filled, you have opted into the new iOS 15 button configuration architecture; by setting the font, you have opted to configure the `attributedTitle`. So to change the text of the title, you need to stick with that. You cannot suddenly revert to the old `setTitle`.

Comment: That's a fair point. I was just confused. Thanks for your help.